# SwiftUI LazyVGrid content compression

Tags: swift, swiftui, layout, grid, lazyvgrid

I am trying to build a grid, consisting of items with image and text under it.
I want all images be the same size and the text to expand cell's height as much as text is needed. But Image is always compressed to preserve all cells equal height and the text not to be truncated.

I've tried a lot of modifiers for LazyVGrid and also setting size parameters for GridItem but still not reached desired result

What should I do to build described UI? Should I use LazyVGrid or it is better to use Grid (the content is static and items quantity is relatively small to think about optimization)?

[image]

```
    let layout = [
        GridItem(),
        GridItem(),
        GridItem()
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(cardsContainer.cards) { card in
                    VStack {
                        if let uiImage = UIImage(named: card.imageName) {
                            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .clipped()
                        }
                        Text(card.name)
                        Text(card.arcana.rawValue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS May be smbdy can advice some good resources about advanced aspects of collections building with SwiftUI cuz I find only basic info about it and only a little info with the comparison of Grids vs Stacks in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you use change the alignment of the `GridItem` to `.top` and then use `.scaledToFit` instead of `.scaledToFill` on the images. Like this:

```swift
let layout = [
    GridItem(alignment: .top),
    GridItem(alignment: .top),
    GridItem(alignment: .top)
]
```

```swift
VStack {
    if let uiImage = UIImage(named: card.imageName) {
        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit() // not .scaledToFill
            .clipped()
    }
    Text(card.name)
    Text(card.arcana.rawValue)
}
```

Otherwise, the way to fix the misaligned grid contents is to make sure the labels always occupy the same space. This is done by establishing a footprint for a standard label, then showing the actual label in an overlay.

There would be two variations of this approach, depending on how you want to handle names that are too long for a single line.

**1. Allow the font to shrink**

You can constrain a name to a single line by applying `.lineLimit(1)`. Then, to avoid truncation (with ellipses), you can allow the font to shrink by using `.minimumScaleFactor`.

```swift
VStack {
    if let uiImage = UIImage(named: card.imageName) {
        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .clipped()
    }
    VStack {
        Text(card.name)
        Text(card.arcana.rawValue)
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
    .hidden() // Hide the footprint
    .overlay {
        VStack {
            Text(card.name)
            Text(card.arcana.rawValue)
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

**2. Allow names to wrap**

If you want to keep the font size constant and allow names to wrap, then the footprint needs to be based on the longest possible name:

```swift
VStack {
    if let uiImage = UIImage(named: card.imageName) {
        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .clipped()
    }
    VStack {
        Text("The longest possible name")
        Text(card.arcana.rawValue)
    }
    .hidden() // Hide the footprint
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
        VStack {
            Text(card.name)
            Text(card.arcana.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ConstantFontSize]

Regarding your question about whether to use `LazyVGrid` or `Grid`, this is probably answered by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid):

> Only use a lazy grid if profiling your app shows that a Grid view performs poorly because it tries to load too many views at once.

If you use a `Grid` then I think you are responsible for ordering the contents into rows, so it is a bit more overhead. But if you want all columns of the grid to have the same width then you don't really need to use a `Grid` at all. You could use a combination of `VStack` (for the overall container) and `HStack` (for the rows) and set `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on every grid item. This will cause them to share the width of an `HStack` equally. This way, you could probably achieve the same result as both the solutions above, but without needing any hidden footprints.

---

*EDIT* The explanation for the first suggestion (using `.scaledToFit` and alignment `.top`) is as follows:

- By default, the `GridItem` have a `.flexible` size. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/griditem/size-swift.enum/flexible(minimum:maximum:)), this means:

> The size of this item is the size of the grid with spacing and inflexible items removed, divided by the number of flexible items, clamped to the provided bounds.

...so the columns will each be given one third of the available width.

- By using `.scaledToFit`, it seems that the size of the image is determined by the width and all images have the same size.
- When the label of an image needs to wrap, it causes the height of the row to increase. This means, if there are any cells in the same row which only have 2-line labels then these cells will have some spare vertical space. By using `alignment: .top`, the content of the cell is aligned at the top and the spare space is all at the bottom. This keeps all the images in the row aligned with each other.
- When `.scaledToFill` is used instead of `scaledToFit` and a label needs to wrap, it seems the images are scaled a bit smaller to give more space for the labels. This spoils the layout. This surprises me a bit, I would have expected the images to be cropped top-and-bottom. But if `.scaledToFit` gives the required result and works reliably then it doesn't really matter how it looks with `.scaledToFill`.

Comment: Wow, what a magic. Thank you! But if I switch to Grid is it possible to have some functionality like self sizing cells in UIKit? Just not to do workarounds like footprints

Comment: Answer updated with more possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much. The firs solution sounds good for me, like there is no "magic" tricks and only simple settings. If it is possible, can you tell few words about how this two settings works together? (I've made GridItem alignment == .top and Image content mode == . scaledToFit)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I've edited it to add an explanation for the first suggestion at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Now everything works as expected